# Populate Object using Google Sheets as the Backend

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-sheets

I'm creating an IOS mobile application that works similar to Food Panda. I am populating objects with info that will be read from a Google Sheet (which is hopefully private).

I have attempted using Firebase, IOS Quickstart, and GoogleDocsBackend but have had no luck (all pods were set up correctly). I am generally lost right now and there does not seem to be much information on the web :(.

Below is the product object I will be populating:

```
class Product {
    public private(set) var productId: String
    public private(set) var productClass: String
    public private(set) var productType: String
    public private(set) var productPrice: Float
    public private(set) var productStarRating: Float
    public private(set) var totalReviews: Int
    public private(set) var productDescription: String
    public private(set) var catagoryID: String
    public private(set) var productImage: String

    init(productId: String, productClass: String, productType: String, productPrice: Float, productStarRating: Float, totalReviews: Int, productDescription: String, catagoryID: String, productImage: String) {
        self.productId = productId
        self.productClass = productClass
        self.productType = productType
        self.productPrice = productPrice
        self.productStarRating = productStarRating
        self.totalReviews = totalReviews
        self.productDescription = productDescription
        self.catagoryID = catagoryID
        self.productImage = productImage
    }
```

Eventually, I will need to have a user Google login system that will prompt them to the main page where all of the product objects will be viewable.

Comment: Hi Chris! Welcome to SO! This isn't a direct answer to your question but I would suggest using a backend service such as Parse. It offers a really user friendly interface for setting up a nice API without much knowledge of how they work. They also have a really good SDK with lots of documentation. Firebase is also a good option but it sounds like you were having trouble understanding it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Will look into it.

Comment: @ColeJames Parse is retired for a couple of years now, however you can host your own Parse server, but that isn't easier than using Firebase IMHO.

Comment: @Chris on SO, if you want help you have to provide some code you wrote, I see that you did that - that's a good start, but I would like to see what you tried with Firebase, continue by posting some code with your try to populate a Product object using Firebase/GoogleDocsBackend.

Comment: @Mihai look into Back4App. I should have mentioned that in my original comment. It does all the hosting for you.

Comment: @ColeJames still, Parse was retired in 2017, there's no future in that. Firebase is a better option, he probably has a hard time with its docs...

Comment: @Mihai I’m not sure where you got that information. The platform is constantly being updated along with all the SDKs for the various platforms. And companies like back4app fully support it. There is a huge active community behind it too. I prefer Firebase as well but I don’t agree with discrediting Parse. This feels like a conversation/debate for another thread though. I was just suggesting an alternative platform for OP.

Comment: @ColeJames this is irrelevant to OP's question, Parse (platform) has been shutdown by Facebook in January 2017.

Comment: I am not seeing any attempt to read your data from Firebase. Also, it's unclear if you're actually *using* Firebase or just google docs. In general you should post code of what you tried. Then we can take a look. Please start with the Firebase Getting Started Guide [Read & Write Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) and also take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, will read and update accordingly. @Jay just for a quick reference, I have been using [IOS quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/ios?ver=swift&hl=zh-cn). Also, have been getting confused when GoogleBackEnd discusses [Mantle](https://github.com/pyro2927/GoogleDocsBackend), and finally, I also tried [something I read that said try Google Auth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in)